# Raspberry Pi Camera image purple

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi

[the carpet/mat should be black](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sxd7L.jpg)    void setup ( int argc,char **argv, RaspiCam_Cv &camera ) {

```
camera.set ( CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,  ( "-w",argc,argv,360 ) );
camera.set ( CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,  ( "-h",argc,argv,240 ) );
camera.set ( CAP_PROP_BRIGHTNESS, ( "-br",argc,argv,50 ) );
camera.set ( CAP_PROP_CONTRAST ,( "-co",argc,argv,50 ) );
camera.set ( CAP_PROP_SATURATION,  ( "-sa",argc,argv,50 ) );
camera.set ( CAP_PROP_GAIN,  ( "-g",argc,argv ,50 ) );
camera.set ( CAP_PROP_FPS,  ( "-fps",argc,argv,100));
}

void capture() {
camera.grab();
camera.retrieve(frame);
cvtColor(frame, frame, COLOR_BGR2RGB);
```

}

the image color is purple. Does it have to do something with the COLOR_BGR2RGB? or something else? thanks

this is the image capturing code that I'm doing. Pls help thank you. Is it possible that the camera isnt working properly or is it the code. thanks. It used to work fine but then at some point it became purple.

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <raspicam_cv.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>
#include <wiringPi.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
using namespace raspicam;

Mat frame;

void Setup ( int argc, char **argv, RaspiCam_Cv &Camera )
{
    Camera.set ( CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,  ( "-w", argc, argv, 400 ));
    Camera.set ( CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,  ( "-h", argc, argv, 240 ));
    Camera.set ( CAP_PROP_BRIGHTNESS, ( "-br", argc, argv, 50 ));
    Camera.set ( CAP_PROP_CONTRAST ,( "-co", argc, argv, 50 ) );
    Camera.set ( CAP_PROP_SATURATION,  ( "-sa", argc, argv, 50 ) );
    Camera.set ( CAP_PROP_GAIN,  ( "-g", argc, argv,50 ) );
    Camera.set ( CAP_PROP_FPS,  ( "-fps", argc,argv,0));

}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    RaspiCam_Cv Camera;
    Setup(argc, argv, Camera);
    cout<<"Connecting to camera"<<endl;
    if (!Camera.open())
    {
         cout<<"Failed to Connect"<<endl;
    }

 cout<<"Camera Id = "<<Camera.getId()<<endl;

 for (int i=0; i<40; i++)
 {
  Camera.grab();
  Camera.retrieve(frame);
  cvtColor(frame,frame, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
  imshow("Sample", frame);
  imwrite("Stop"+to_string(i)+".jpg" , frame);
  waitKey();
 }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't show the code that created the image file you shared.

Comment: Hello. Yes most probably linked to RGB ordering.

Comment: @MarkSetchell just shared the code. could you look into it now thanks:)

Comment: You ran BGR2GRAY and saved the result and it's magenta?